# Wordpress orderby meta_value not ordering properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'events' and I am to display the first 4 more recent events in event date order on the home page. I have got the events to show on the home page however the ordering doesn't seem to be working (see below the example). It seems to be ordering in its own way.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'events', 'meta_key' => 'event-date', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$events = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That is my code and here are the results (the dates) I get back.

```
16/04/2014
16/05/2014
19/03/2014
25/02/2014
27/02/2014
28/02/2014
```

As you can see, this is not ordering by ASC so what have I done wrong?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the format of event-date? If you look at the result, events are ordered only by date. Its not considering month n year. Try to update the date to datetime format and then check it.

Comment: In your database, you should have the date with datetime format. so before saving event date, convert date to datetime format.            $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $eventdate) ); then save $mysqldate to database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use meta_value_num instead of meta_value in orderby parameter. Use following code:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'events', 
        'meta_key'          => 'event-date', 
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num', 
        'order'             => 'ASC', 
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
        );

$events = new WP_Query( $args );
```